# Why drawablePadding is not working in Button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to increase gap between the drawable icon on the left and the text on the right. I am using drawablePadding. But this does not seem to have any effect. Here is the code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
    tools:context=".Authentication">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/google_sign_in_btn"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/g_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:textColor="#8A000000"
        android:text="@string/sign_in_with_google_txt"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:drawablePadding="100dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the result -

[image]

Comment: Can you share your Google logo?

Comment: @RaoArsalan you can download the files for all resolutions from the link on this page - https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines

Comment: did you check after restart your android studio? I checked it's working fine.

Comment: @RaoArsalan I tried restarting Android Studio. But it still isn't working. No matter what value I set for drawablePadding, nothing changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

drawablePadding won't work on materialButtons as the materialButton class reads the drawable padding from `app:iconPadding` attribute instead of `drawablePadding`.

If you look at the source code of the material button you will see this :

`iconPadding = attributes.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.MaterialButton_iconPadding, 0);`

here you can see that icon's padding is read from iconPadding attribute.
comparing it to TextView (Button extends textView) we have :

```
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          int attr = a.getIndex(i);

         switch (attr) {
         
         //lots of cases

         case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextView_drawablePadding:
              drawablePadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, drawablePadding);
              break;

                       }
                                }
```

To get an idea of how these xml attributes work, see [Creating a View Class](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I changed my Button to https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton

Like this you can use the **app:iconPadding** attribute in the Material Button instead of **android:drawablePadding**, to increase or decrease the padding between the drawable and the text. This worked fine for me. You can even set negative values like **app:iconPadding="-5"** which results in an even smaller padding between the drawable and the text.

Like for instance:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_drawable"
                android:text="Your Text"
                app:iconPadding="10dp"/>
```

I hope this helps!